# Cannot use `FormBody.Builder` from OKHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

I;m trying to do a post request using OKHttp on Android. I have looked at a few examples and this is what I have constructed

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/test";

RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("access_token", "test")
        .add("name", "David")
        .build();
```

But `Builer` is red in Android studio and if I hover my mouse over it, it says "Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder'"

Below are my imports

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Callback;
import com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Request;
import com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody;
import com.squareup.okhttp.Response;

import java.io.IOException;
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-smsmms:4.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Paste dependency link of httpOK which is used in your gradle.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Remove your imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your import.

Use this

```
import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
```